# React Native Category Tabs - each tab renders different category

Tags: react-native

I am currently trying to implement a browse screen, where users can pick a specific category from a ScrollView which renders the posts related to that category.

My api gets all the post data from the backend and for each post i have a parameter call categoryId.

What i am trying to do is, for example if one of my categories is sports. when the user selects the sports tab, a flatlist with all the posts about sports should be rendered.

With this current implementation, i have my category tabs and when i select anyone of the tabs all the posts get rendered not the posts for that specific category.

Here is my code:

```
function SearchScreen({ navigation }) {
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const loadPosts = async () => {
setLoading(true);
const response = await postsApi.getPosts(page);
setLoading(false);

if (!response.ok) return setError(true);

setError(false);
setPosts(response.data);
};

const[page,setPage]=useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
loadPosts();
 }, []);

const categories = [
{
  label: "Sports",
  id: 1,
},
{
  label: "Fashion",
  id: 2,
},
{
  label: "News",
  id: 3,
   },
  ];

 const[label,setLabel]=useState('Sports')
 const[dataList,setDataList]=useState(posts)

const setLabelFilter=label=>{
setLabel(label)
}

return (
<>
  <ActivityIndicator visible={loading} />
  <Screen style={styles.screen}>
    {error && (
      <>
        <View style={styles.error}>
          <AppText>Could not retrieve posts from server.</AppText>
          <AppButton title="Retry" onPress={loadPosts} />
        </View>
      </>
    )}
    <ScrollView 
    horizontal 
    style={{flexDirection:"row",
    alignContent:"center",
    width:Dimensions.get('window').width/1.05,
    marginBottom:20,
    }} 
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    >
    {categories.map(e=>(
            <TouchableOpacity 
            style={[
                {paddingHorizontal:10,paddingBottom:10},
                label===e.label && 
                {borderBottomWidth:3,
                borderBottomColor:colors.primary,
                borderRadius:2,
            }
                ]} 
                onPress={()=>setLabelFilter(e.label)}
                >
            <AppText style={[{fontWeight:"500",color:colors.medium},label===e.label && 
{color:colors.primary,fontWeight:"700"}]}>{e.label}</AppText>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    ))}
    </ScrollView>

    <FlatList
      data={posts} // to have all the data
      keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
        <Card
          title={item.title}
          subTitle={item.subTitle}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.POST_DETAILS, {post:item,index})}            
  />
      )}
    />
  </Screen>
</> 
);
}
```

When i do console.log(posts), here is what my response looks like:

```
Object {
"Category": Object {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Sports",
},
"categoryId": 3,
"createdAt": "2020-11-18T13:43:19.616Z",
"deletedAt": null,
"id": 506,
"subtTitle": "test",
"title": "test",
"updatedAt": "2020-11-23T06:57:44.150Z",
"userId": 1,
 },
```

I have thought of changing my API call to get the category by its id then include all posts for each specific category but that did not work, so i went with API call the gets all the posts.

*Update*

```
 const[label,setLabel]=useState('Sports')

 const setLabelFilter=label=>{
setLabel(label)
  }

 const [currentCategoryId, setCurrentCategoryId] = useState()

 const toggleBrands = (categoryId) => {
 setCurrentCategoryId(categoryId)
 setLabel(label)
   };

 return(
 <ScrollView 
    horizontal 
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    >
    {categories.map(e=>(
            <TouchableOpacity 
                key={e.id}
                onPress={()=>{toggleBrands(e.id),
                setLabelFilter(e.label)}}
                selected={e.id === currentCategoryId}
                >
            <AppText>{e.label}</AppText>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    ))}
    </ScrollView>

    <FlatList
      data={currentCategoryId ? 
posts.filter(post=>post.categoryId===currentCategoryId
        ):posts}
```

I tried the following code can someone tell me if it is correct or not?

Comment: So what is actually the problem you encountered ?

Comment: the problem i encountered is that when i press on a category i want to render only the posts for that category not all the posts

Comment: @KenLee the response from console.log(posts) is just to show that for each post fetched from backend the categoryId is included

Comment: The normal way to do it is: 1. when you click an item on the Flatlist, it will retrieve data (say from a php , with the category as a parameter passed to the php) , and then the php file will , depending on your category parameter, pass the data of that category back. But can you tell me by what method do you get the data ?

Comment: I have a ScrollView that includes the title of each category, when i press on any of the categories in the scrollView i want to render a flatList for the posts of that specific category.

Comment: Since FlatList is a PureComponent, it assumes that the data is an immutable object and that any change in data is done by setting a new data source object in the state object.  For your case, it is the data={posts}

Comment: so i need to change my data={} so that it filters the flatlist based on the categoryId ?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: Do you mind giving me a hand with that, since i do not know how?

Answer (score 0):

To give you an example, say you will first click an item in a Flatlist (showing all categories) on screen A, and then the system will be navigated to screen B (with Flatlist showing the items of the selected category only)

The normal method is to dynamically display just the data of selected category, say by a php script (for this example, it is sjson.php)

For screen A, it will be like this:

Screen A GetFlatListItem function :

```
GetFlatListItem (fruit_name) {
   this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {unitserial: fruit_name}) 
   }
```

Screen A Flatlist can be like this :

```
          data={ this.state.dataSource }
          
          ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
 
          renderItem={({item}) => 
          
 <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent:'flex-start'}}>
<Text  onPress={this.GetFlatListItem.bind(this, item.serial)} > 
          {item.ok}</Text>
</View>
```

For screen B, it will be like this:

```
const enstring='https://www.test.com/sjson.php?serial=' + this.props.route.params.unitserial ;


       return fetch(enstring)
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
             

           this.setState({
             dataSource: responseJson
           }, function() {
             // In this block you can do something with new state.
           });
              
              
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
         });
         }
```

and the Flatlist can be like :

```
<FlatList
       data={ this.state.dataSource }

>
```

Please note that you will need to modify your codes to suit your needs. The above is just an example.

Comment: thank you for the example, is there a way instead of navigating to a new screen to show the rendered data, i render the data below after i select a category item from flatlist?

Comment: Sure, you may not need to use navigation. But you will need to change your data state when you kick the GetFlatListItem function, so that it will be reflected in the next Flatlist

Comment: how do i do that if you can please help with that?

Comment: say if you have three categories, the 1st category data is Json1, the 2nd one is Json2, and the 3rd category is Json3, then in the GetFlatListeItem, you may use this.setState({dataSource: Json1} or this.setState({dataSource: Json2} or this.setState({dataSource: Json3} , according to the category the user clicks . Please try to code first and see whether you still have problem

Comment: ok will try it now, i have a question will it be better instead of having an API call that gets all my posts, i create one like this /categories/${id} and use this or it does not matter?

Comment: I think you are in the right direction. Please try and see

Comment: so, i replace my scrollView with a flatlist?

Answer (score 0):

First Define States :

```
      const [apiRespPonse, setApiRespone] = useState("");
  const [selectedTabData, setSelectedPost] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("Sports");
```

In your api call set The Response :

```
const fetchAllPost = () => {
    
    setApiRespone([]);
      const newArr = apiRespPonse.filter(obj => obj.label===category);
            setSelectedPost(newArr)
  };
```

For your render option use filter for array to get selected tab data :

```
 return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
     
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
         {categories.map((item, index) => {
          return <Text onPress={()=>{
            setCategory(categories[index])
            const newArr = apiRespPonse.filter(obj => obj.label===category);
            setSelectedPost(newArr)
          }} style={styles.title}>{item.label}</Text>;
        })}
        </View>
     
      </View>


<FlatList
data={selectedTabData}/>
    </View>
  );
};
```

May be it can help.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, so i add the code inside your fetchAllPosts inside my loadPosts function?

Comment: Yes just update the selected category. You have done every thing is right just the filter thing you have to do and set the filtered array in your state for flatlist. I hope we are on same page.

Comment: i have updated my question with an implementation i was trying can please have a look at it and tell me what is missing?

Comment: What are the error you facing? Can you replace the filter category method that i  provided. Can you print the log?

Comment: I dont understand what exactly should i replace?

Comment: Wait the code you have added in flatlist data can you  set it in the other piece.  What exactly problem you are facing. Can you provide me the code to expo? Please refer this [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-agnesi-y6y3j?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I dont get an error, i am not getting the correct functionality instead of getting the posts for each category i keep getting all the posts. where do you want me to set the flatlist data code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225279/discussion-between-rajshekhar-yadav-and-kd12345).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to refresh flat list content with the selected category. I think the code you have before the updates does everything you need with little updates. Here is the part of code you just need to update

```
{categories.map((e,index)=>(
  <TouchableOpacity 
    ...
    style={[
      ...
      index===page && {
        borderBottomWidth:3,
        borderBottomColor:colors.primary,
        borderRadius:2,
    }]
    onPress={()=>{setPage(index)}}
  >
  ...
  </TouchableOpacity>
)}
```

Make sure `postsApi.getPosts(page);` returns correct data based on the given `page` parameter.